# Exceptions while processing modified wordcount java program for big data file with 64bits data sets

Tags: java, hadoop

Here is my code:

```
public class WordCount {

public static class TokenizerMapper extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, IntWritable> {

private final static IntWritable one = new IntWritable(1);
private Text word = new Text();

public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
   StringTokenizer itr = new StringTokenizer(value.toString());
    int j = 1, count = 0, i=0;
  while (itr.hasMoreTokens()) {

    if(j == 1)
    {
    itr.nextToken();
    j++;
    }
    else if (j == 2)
    {
    count = Integer.parseInt(itr.nextToken());
    j++;
    }
    else
    {
    for (i=1;i<=count;i++)
    {
    word.set(itr.nextToken());
    context.write(word, one);
    }
    j=1;
    }       
  }

}
}

public static class IntSumReducer extends Reducer<Text,IntWritable,Text,IntWritable> {
private IntWritable result = new IntWritable();

public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<IntWritable> values, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
  int sum = 0;
  for (IntWritable val : values) {
    sum += val.get();
  }
  result.set(sum);
  context.write(key, result);
}
}
```

And when I am running it for a 35.4GB file with 64bits size data sets, it shows me the following error:

```
Error: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "9267242563148306650"
```

Also, the following errors after adding BigInteger :

Changes done in the code:

```
public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
   StringTokenizer itr = new StringTokenizer(value.toString());
    int j = 1, i=0;
    int c;
    BigInteger count = new BigInteger("0");
  while (itr.hasMoreTokens()) {

    if(j == 1)
    {
    itr.nextToken();
    j++;
    }
    else if (j == 2)
    {
    count = new BigInteger(itr.nextToken());
    j++;
    }
    else
    {
    c=count.intValue();
    for (i=1;i<=c;i++)
    {
    word.set(itr.nextToken());
    context.write(word, one);
    }
    j=1;
    }       
  }
```

Error1: 
java.util.NoSuchElementexception (mostly by stringtokenizer)

Error2:
java.lang.NumberFormatException

How do I go about resolving this issue?
Thanks!

Comment: It's not that line which creates the issue. That part works well. But, the other half of the loop doesn't take the numbers.

Comment: Yes it is, you have an integer overflow. However, I just checked withi long, it is not enough either. Use `BigInteger` .

Comment: Can word.set() be modified to accept long type words?

Comment: When i try doing Long.parseLong it gives me "possible loss of precision" error

Comment: I tried with Long and got the same error as with Integer. You need to use big integers.

Comment: How to use BigInteger? there is no such library defined for it, or am i missing something?

Comment: You are new to stackoverflow. Welcome. Your question is ok but can you please improve the code formatting?

Comment: BigInteger is a class of the standard library. Did you googled it ? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html

Comment: After using BigInteger, now am getting java.util.NoSuchElementexception Can anyone help with this? Whi is this error popping up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an integer overflow (`int` and `long` variables are bounded, see the following [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) for further details), you must use `BigInteger` class to handle such huge numbers.

Comment: After using BigInteger, now am getting java.util.NoSuchElementexception Can anyone help with this? Why is this error popping up?

Comment: It is a completely different question, probably related to the `StringTokenizer` (which is deprecated by the way). Please accept an answer here and post a new one talking specifically of your new issue

Answer (score 0):

A Java long is a signed 64-bit integer, so it can fit fit 63 bits worth of number. int is 32-bit.

The problem is that 9267242563148306650 doesn't fit in 63 bits, nevertheless 31 bits. So when you try to parseInt the number, it just doesn't fit. You'll need to use something like BigInteger to store the values.

Comment: After using BigInteger, now am getting java.util.NoSuchElementexception Can anyone help with this? Why is this error popping up?

Comment: @coder That depends on how you are using it, and where the exception to being thrown. As Dici suggests, might be better as separate question. Either that or ADD (don't change the existing contents of the question, as they will make the issue you had the answers to it useless to others in the future) to include the new code and the issues you are having.

Comment: i have ADDed the changes without much modification in the previous question. Now can you please help me with this.